# hibernate3-maven-plugin generates java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.util.ReflectHelper

Tags: maven, jpa-2.0, ddl, hibernate3-maven-plugin

I am trying to generate a schema (ddl) from my orm.xml file.  I'm using hibernate3-maven-plugin.  I'm using JPA with hibernate as the implementation, but am open to other implementations or maven plugins.  The code in my pom.xml is:

```
 <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>                
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate3-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>

            <configuration>
                <hibernatetool>
                    <jpaconfiguration persistenceunit="unitname" />

                    <hbm2ddl export="false" create="true"
                 update="true" format="true" outputfilename="schemaDiff.ddl" />

                </hibernatetool>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>            
    </plugins>
</build>
```

The command I run is:

> mvn hibernate3:hbm2ddl -e

The error I received is:

> Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/util/ReflectHelper
>           at org.hibernate.tool.ant.JPAConfigurationTask.createConfiguration(JPAConfigurationTask.java:32)
>           at org.hibernate.tool.ant.ConfigurationTask.getConfiguration(ConfigurationTask.java:54)
>           at org.hibernate.tool.ant.HibernateToolTask.getConfiguration(HibernateToolTask.java:302)
>           at org.hibernate.tool.ant.Hbm2DDLExporterTask.createExporter(Hbm2DDLExporterTask.java:51)
>           at org.hibernate.tool.ant.ExporterTask.execute(ExporterTask.java:39)
>           at org.hibernate.tool.ant.HibernateToolTask.execute(HibernateToolTask.java:186)
>           at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>           at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
>           ... 28 more
>
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.util.ReflectHelper
>           at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:50)
>           at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:244)
>           at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:230)
>           ... 40 more

Comment: See that answer for JPA 2.1 full solution :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27314165/generate-ddl-script-at-maven-build-with-hibernate4-jpa-2-1/27314166#27314166

Answer (score 1):

George Herolyants presents a solution here.

http://doingenterprise.blogspot.com/2012/05/schema-generation-with-hibernate-4-jpa.html