# How to generate DDL script from annotated classes using Hibernate 5?

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-5.x

I've seen a lot of results regarding generate SQL from Hibernate beans, however, I am still a little bit confused regarding the best way to do that, and also compatibility with Hibernate versions. I have tried some of these examples I found and none of them seems working well with the version of Hibernate I am using (5.2.11). I have annotated classes, not .xml files. And using a persistence.xml. Any idea how to correctly generate my DDL files?

Comment: post your code so that we can check the issue.

Comment: Hey, after some tries... I was able to generate my SQL script using Hibernate tools. I followed the information in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34897410/auto-generate-data-schema-from-jpa-2-1-annotated-entity-classes-without-a-databa