# Getting Exception when upgrading Hiberate 5.0.2.Final to 5.2.6.Final

Tags: java, spring, hibernate-entitymanager

I am getting exception when i am trying to upgrade latest Hiberate version. It works smooth in 5.0.2.Final.

This is my maven configuration

```
<java.version>1.8</java.version>
<servlet.api>3.1.0</servlet.api>
<servlet.jsp>2.2</servlet.jsp>
<hibernate.version>5.0.2.Final</hibernate.version>
<oracle.ojdbc6>11.2.0.2.0</oracle.ojdbc6>
<spring.version>4.2.6.RELEASE</spring.version>
<spring.security.version>4.2.1.RELEASE</spring.security.version>
<spring.data.version>1.9.4.RELEASE</spring.data.version>
<thymeleaf.version>3.0.2.RELEASE</thymeleaf.version>
<thymeleaf.security.version>3.0.0.RELEASE</thymeleaf.security.version>
<jackson.version>2.8.4</jackson.version>
```

Exception

```
03-Jan-2017 11:51:34.421 WARN [localhost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.ExceptionHandlerLoggedImpl.handleException GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Error executing DDL via JDBC Statement
 org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL via JDBC Statement
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:67)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applySqlString(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:524)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applySqlStrings(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:470)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.createTable(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:273)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.GroupedSchemaMigratorImpl.performTablesMigration(GroupedSchemaMigratorImpl.java:71)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.performMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:203)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.doMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:110)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:183)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:72)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:309)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:445)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:889)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:60)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:343)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:318)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1054)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:829)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:444)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:326)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4810)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5255)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:939)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1812)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00955: name is already used by an existing object

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:440)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:396)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:837)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:445)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:191)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:523)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.doOall8(T4CStatement.java:193)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.executeForRows(T4CStatement.java:999)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1315)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeInternal(OracleStatement.java:1890)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.execute(OracleStatement.java:1855)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatementWrapper.execute(OracleStatementWrapper.java:304)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.DelegatingStatement.execute(DelegatingStatement.java:290)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.DelegatingStatement.execute(DelegatingStatement.java:290)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:54)
    ... 41 more
```

Comment: If possible: use an empty database (without tabes, indexes, contraints, triggers,...) and try it again.

Comment: not helped, throws same exception

Comment: If the same exception occures even with an empty database, then something must been wrong with the mapping or some other stange error. I would let Hibernate instruct to generate the ddl script (instead of executing it) and then I would check the script or execute it line by line with an SQL Tool. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27314165/generate-ddl-script-at-maven-build-with-hibernate4-jpa-2-1

Answer (score 0):

Setting default schema may solve your problem.

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
  <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
  <property name="packagesToScan" value="ir.asta.training.contacts.entities" />
  <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
     <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
  </property>
  <property name="jpaProperties">
     <props>
        <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop> 
        <prop key="hibernate.default_schema">your_oracle_user</prop>
     </props>
  </property>
```